# Sur le mot « raisonné(e) »

Tags: sens, synonymes

L'un des livres d'Alexandre Kojève s’appelle [*Essai d'une histoire raisonnée de la philosophie païenne*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandre_Koj%C3%A8ve).

[Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/raisonner/66274/synonyme) en donne une liste entière de synonymes:

```
analyser
cogiter (familier)
étudier
méditer
passer au crible
penser
ratiociner (littéraire)
réfléchir
```

Mais, d'une manière ou d'une autre, je sens qu'aucun de ces sens n'est celui qui illustre le mieux le sens que l'auteur de ce livre a voulu donner à ce mot ; et la traduction anglaise, *reasoned*, n'est pas, dans ce cas, très bonne, non plus.

Donc quel mot, à votre avis, serait le meilleur synonyme pour *raisonné(e)* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je ne pense pas que la recherche de synonymes soit (toujours) le bon moyen pour comprendre le sens d'un mot. En tous les cas ça ne me semble pas le meilleur ici. Et aucun des participes passés des verbes employés dans la question ne conviendrait ici pour remplacer l'adjectif *raisonné* tel qu'il est employé dans le titre de l'ouvrage évoqué dans la question.

Une « histoire raisonnée » est une histoire « fondée sur le raisonnement »  « qui résulte d'un examen réfléchi des raisons ». Ce sens découle du sens suivant de *raisonner* trouvé dans le ([TLF. II. 2.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/Raisonn%C3%A9)) :

> Trouver, donner un fondement intellectuel à quelque chose, le construire, lui donner un cadre rationnel.

Une « histoire raisonnée » va donc retracer les bases théoriques et le développement de l'objet d'étude en soumettant tous les arguments à la raison.

Peut-être eût-il été plus facile de chercher directement un synonyme de *raisonné*.

> philosophé, discuté, pensé, spéculé ([Cordial](http://dictionnaire.cordial-enligne.fr/definition/raisonn%C3%A9))

On retrouve ce sens de *raisonné* dans la notion de « catalogue raisonné » qui est un ouvrage qui recense toutes les œuvres d'un artiste. Dans ce cas l'anglais ne traduit pas et [emploie le mot français](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalogue_raisonn%C3%A9).

L'« Histoire raisonnée » est une concept philosophique français en vogue au 17<sup>e</sup> en France. Le plus célèbre de ces ouvrages est l' *[Encyclopédie, ou dictionnaire raisonné des sciences, des arts et des métiers](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclop%C3%A9die_ou_Dictionnaire_raisonn%C3%A9_des_sciences,_des_arts_et_des_m%C3%A9tiers)* (communément appelé « l'Encyclopédie de Diderot »). Ouvrage traduit en anglais par : *Encyclopaedia, or a Systematic Dictionary of the Sciences, Arts, and Crafts*). *Raisonné* est ici traduit par "systematic".  Mais le choix aurait pu aussi être fait de traduire par "comprehensive".
En français on parle de *[grammaire raisonnée](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1237859/f7.image)*, on peut rapprocher ça de l'anglais "[*comprehensive grammar*](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=comprehensive%20grammar&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=)".

J'ai cherché pour savoir si cet ouvrage de Kojève avait été traduit en anglais, et il semblerait que non d'après ce qu'a donné ma recherche sur WorldCat.

Comment: "Et aucun des participes passés des verbes employés dans la question ne conviendrait ici pour remplacer l'adjectif raisonné tel qu'il est employé dans le titre de l'ouvrage évoqué dans la question." Hence my question.